# Hourly Time Sheets Database Design

Tags: database, database-design

Building an internal web-based project management tool for my company. Need some help with the database design for the timesheet component.

We currently use an MS Excel file where: 
Column headings - Days of the week
Rows - Time of the day with 30 minutes per row (Row1: 9:00AM, Row2: 9:30AM and so on)

Each cell in the table has a dropwdown menu that fetches from a set of predefined tasks set by a manager and the employee selects one of the tasks against that day and that particular 30 minute time slot.

I want the front end interface to remain the same for the employees.

Need help with designing a database that supports this. I'm open to any suggestions/changes in the restrictions I laid out if it allows for better efficiency. Thank you!

Comment: seems like you need to hire a developer to do it! Database design and UI can be complex

Comment: @gavgrif Not really. If what I've asked for is incredibly complex to implement, I'm open to a more simple solution. UI doesn't have to be Excel like. Just throwing out ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're after?

**Task** (all of the tasks an employee might be assigned)

- PK: Id
- Name
- ... other details ...

**Employee**

- PK: Id
- Name
- ... other details ...

**EmployeeTask** (the list of tasks that have been assigned to an employee)

- PK: Id
- FK: TaskId
- FK: EmployeeId

**TimePeriod** (the row labels)

- PK: Id
- Start (9:30, 10:00 etc.)

**Timesheet** (chops out a region of time and says it's one thing - gives column headings)

- PK: Id
- Start date
- End date (don't need this if timesheets cover the same length of time)

**EmployeeTimesheetCell**

- PK: Id
- FK: TimesheetId
- FK: EmployeeId
- FK: TimePeriodId
- FK: TaskId
- Date or day of the week
- Time spent

You'd probably want some kind of status or Finished Date on Task and/or EmployeeTask, so that old finished tasks don't clutter up the GUI.